# Where can I find a list of Fantasy Grounds mini-dungeons/adventures, by level?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, fantasy-grounds

Our group wants to run sporadic one-shots, and we haven't found an efficient way to sort through the published mini-dungeons/short adventures, either on the FG store or through Steam.

Currently, we search for "mini-dungeon" and then have to check each, one by one, to see the level range. Is there an index/catalog somewhere? Or some way of further filtering?

Ideally, we'd like to say "let's play next week—what level are we starting? Sweet, let see what's available for that level. Done."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a whim I emailed the support folks at Fantasy Grounds and was provided with the list provided below.

Another user pointed out that many of the products are not available on the FG Store as of this posting (June 29, 2017).

A link to the original spreadsheet is posted below the table.

The table as produced:

$$
\begin{array}{|r|l|l|l|}
\hline
\mbox{ID} & \mbox{Title} & \mbox{Target # PCs} & \mbox{Target levels}
\\\hline
1 &  \mbox{Buried Council Chambers} & 4-6 & 2-3
\\2 &  \mbox{Hobgoblin Lair} & 4 & 1
\\3 &  \mbox{Shrine of the Earth Barons} & 4-6 & 10-11
\\4 &  \mbox{Summoner's Remorse} & 4-6 & 5-6
\\5 &  \mbox{The Soularium} & 4-6 & 1
\\6 &  \mbox{Abandoned Shrine} & 4-5 & 5-6
\\7 &  \mbox{The Pententieyrie} & 4-5 & 4-5
\\8 &  \mbox{Carrionholme} & 4-5 & 4-5
\\9 &  \mbox{Tiikeri's Revenge} & 4-5 & 6-7
\\10 & \mbox{Ghastardly Deeds} & 4-6 & 6-7
\\11 & \mbox{Buta No Shiro} & 4 & 10
\\12 & \mbox{Nekh-ta-Nebi's Tomb} & 4 & 5
\\13 & \mbox{The Case of the Scrupulous Pawnbroker} & 4 & 3
\\14 & \mbox{The Soul of a Prince} & 4 & 9-11
\\15 & \mbox{Torment at Torni Tower} & 4-5 & 5-6
\\16 & \mbox{The Halls of Hellfire} & 4-5 & 10-11
\\17 & \mbox{Shadows of Madness} & 4-6 & 6-7
\\18 & \mbox{Neotomas' Paradise} & 3-4 & 3-4
\\19 & \mbox{The Goblin Warren} & 4 & 1
\\20 & \mbox{Sepulchre of the Witching Hour's Sage} & 4 & 5
\\21 & \mbox{Daenyr’s Return} & 4-6 & 8-9
\\22 & \mbox{Pleasure Den} & 4-6 & 7-8
\\23 & \mbox{The Aura of Profit} & 4-6 & 1
\\24 & \mbox{The Lapis Maiden of Serena Hortum} & 4-6 & 6
\\25 & \mbox{The Choker Lair} & 4-6 & 6
\\26 & \mbox{Sanctuary of Exsanguination} & 4-5 & 4
\\27 & \mbox{Kaltenheim} & 4 & 9
\\28 & \mbox{Throne of the Dwellers in Dreams} & 6 & 5-6
\\29 & \mbox{Heart of the Sacred Dawn} & 4-5 & 20
\\30 & \mbox{The Burning Tree of Coilltean Grove} & 4-5 & 4
\\31 & \mbox{Dwarven Dread} & 4-6 & 5-6
\\32 & \mbox{Howling Halls} & 4 & 7
\\33 & \mbox{The Legacy of Theft} & 3-5 & 6-7
\\34 & \mbox{Mysteries of the Endless Maze} & 4-5 & 5
\\35 & \mbox{The Queen's Estuary} & 4 & 5
\\36 & \mbox{The Scrag Queen's Sanctuary} & 4 & 5
\\   & \quad\mbox{(The Dragon Queen's Sanctuary)} & &
\\37 & \mbox{The Unreachable Terror} & 4-6 & 9-10
\\38 & \mbox{The Spinner's Hole} & 4 & 1
\\39 & \mbox{We All Start Somewhere} & 2-4 & 1-3
\\40 & \mbox{The Kabandha's Request} & 4 & 5
\\41 & \mbox{Feischkammer} & 4 & 7
\\42 & \mbox{The Dreamer's Shrine} & 4 & 2
\\43 & \mbox{Thelamos} & 4 & 4
\\44 & \mbox{The Ascent of Tempest Tower} & 3-4 & 20
\\45 & \mbox{Peril at Lamiaks Bridge} & 3-5 & 4-5
\\46 & \mbox{The Gallery of Gears} & 4 & 9
\\47 & \mbox{Stowaway on the Singing Sea} & 3-4 & 5-8
\\48 & \mbox{Pit Your Wits} & 4-6 & 1-2
\\49 & \mbox{Doubt Not That Stars Are Fire} & 4-6 & 2-3
\\50 & \unicode{x201C}\mbox{When Goblins Die & No Comets are Seen"} & 4-6 & 3-4
\\51 & \mbox{There Are More Things in the Planes and the Earth} & 4-6 & 4-5
\\52 & \mbox{Look Not With Thine Eyes But Thine Mind} & 4-6 & 5-6
\\53 & \mbox{Ne'er Trust The White Wolf's Tameness} & 4-6 & 6-7
\\54 & \mbox{Uneasy Rests the Crown'd Head} & 4-6 & 7-8
\\55 & \mbox{Chrome Devils of the Swamp} & 4 & 6
\\56 & \mbox{The Siren's Lament} & 4-5 & 4
\\57 & \mbox{Last Stand of the Forgotten Pirate} & 4 & 3-5
\\58 & \mbox{The Palace of Ahmad Sahir} & 4 & 6
\\59 & \mbox{With a Candlestick} & 4 & 3-5
\\60 & \mbox{The Unquenched Thirst} & 4-5 & 3
\\61 & \mbox{The Cackling Madness of Umberstone Manor} & 3-4 & 13-15
\\62 & \mbox{What the Dickens} & 4 & 8
\\63 & \mbox{The World Forge} & 4 & 11
\\64 & \mbox{I’ll Plague Both Your Houses} & 4-6 & 9-10
\\65 & \mbox{The Blight} & 4 & 3
\\66 & \unicode{x201C}\mbox{Words Fly Up & Thoughts Remain Below"} & 4-6 & 8-9
\\67 & \mbox{What Canst Work I’ th’ Earth So Fast} & 4-6 & 11-12
\\68 & \mbox{Awakening the Elder} & 4 & 9
\\69 & \mbox{The Broken River} & 4 & 2
\\70 & \mbox{I Am Not of Your Element} & 4-6 & 13-14
\\71 & \unicode{x201C}\mbox{The Unwise Young & They Say do Ne'er Live Long"} & 4-6 & 12-13
\\72 & \mbox{The Stuff of Dreams} & 4-6 & 10-11
\\73 & \mbox{True Lovers Run Into Strange Capers} & 4-6 & 14-15
\\74 & \mbox{Temple of the Secret Power} & 4-6 & 6
\\75 & \mbox{The Garden of Death} & 4 & 4
\\76 & \mbox{The Great Library} & 4 & 7
\\77 & \mbox{Maw of the Dark Tide} & 5-8 & 15-20
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

[Original Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5s1IX38eLfGOUZOelJWYlI3Y3F4U19ab3ZhejloOFBQQXFJ)

Comment: Thank you for the table edit. I thought about copy/pasting from the spreadsheet but it was late and I was tired. Will Try Harder! next time :)

Comment: Looks like a good portion of these are not available on Fantasy Grounds format. Only 1-20 are listed on FG Store.